# Selecting records by title

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to write my new framework and practice my skills, and I want to select articles by their name `index.php?article=the name of the article`

Then I try to select it

```
    $this->db->connect();

    //sanitize data
    $title = $this->db->escape($title);

    $this->db->prepare("
    SELECT
        `date`, `title`, `content`, `author`
    FROM
        `articles`
    WHERE
        `title` like '%$title%'

    LIMIT 1 ;  ");

    //execute query
    $this->db->query();
    $article = $this->db->fetch('array');
    return $article;
```

it does not work...

When I try to run query directly on the database - it does not work(0 rows returned) (see below)

```
SELECT 
    `date`, `title`, `content`, `author`
FROM
    `articles`
WHERE
    `title` like '%How to generate Lorem Ipsum%';
```

Database sample:

```
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `date` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `content` text NOT NULL,
   `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;

LOCK TABLES `articles` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `articles` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `articles` VALUES
  (1,'Dec 12, 2008','How to generate Lorem Ipsum','Nam accumsan enim tristique urna commodo mollis. Etiam eget leo est. Donec tincidunt quam nec nulla pulvinar sed tristique lorem tincidunt. Pellentesque nibh lectus; suscipit sed ullamcorper sed, laoreet ut tortor. Morbi ut ante tellus. Integer vitae felis id justo tempor adipiscing. Curabitur eget ipsum et urna ultricies pulvinar. Fusce enim dolor, interdum eu egestas vel, iaculis eget nisl. Aenean pretium diam accumsan quam tincidunt sit amet dictum lorem scelerisque. In gravida ultricies aliquet. Phasellus porta erat vel augue sodales feugiat! Pellentesque mattis malesuada ultrices. Mauris eleifend mi quis arcu tincidunt vehicula! Nam sodales commodo lacus, et commodo metus venenatis vel. Sed mollis molestie congue. Nulla ante leo, aliquet et convallis sed; consequat sed turpis. Duis augue leo, adipiscing at venenatis eget, eleifend vitae velit! ','John Squibb'),
  (2,'Jan 03, 1988','Using __autoload','Now in order to try out our new library and driver setup, we have to first make some changes to the way files are served in our framework. Open up the router.php file located in the controllers folder that we created in the first part of this tutorial. If we look at our __autoload function we\'ll see the code we wrote to handle the \'lazy loading\' of our models. Since we used the same naming convention for our libraries and drivers, a quick modification to this code will allow us to load those as easily.','Frank Rabbit');
```

Comment: Do you at any point assign `$_GET['article']` to `$title`?

Comment: It runs correctly for me the example with the hardcoded title.

Comment: BTW, in the PHP code you are using prepared statements WRONG! You should put a placeholder, not the real value, and then bind the value to the placeholder: `$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT foo FROM articles WHERE title = :title'); $stmt->bindValue(':title', $_GET['title']); $stmt->execute();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your way of preparing query has got no sense. Prepare statements are used when you need to bind variables on it. You can simply do like:

```
$this->db->select('date,title,content,author')
         ->like('title',$title, 'both')
         ->get('articles');
```

But, if you want to prepare statement, try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT date, title, content, author FROM articles 
        WHERE title like %?% limit 1";
$this->db->query($sql, array($title));
```

Comment: I sanitize input before; nonetheless I have another problem here-- I can't select the data. It works fine if I use the ID, but won't select by name... I am thinking that It might have to do something with godaddy.com (this is where I run my DB)

Comment: as you mentioned on question that the query works on database, this should also work

Answer (score 0):

If you already set `$_GET['article']` to `$titles`, i don't see any problem except than you select incorrect table or database. refert to your connection string and check if it is correct database. check if you are in local or remote database.

EDIT1 ; perhaps change `title like '%$title%'` to `title like '%".$title."%'` useful.

Comment: It works on the sqlfddle... I h=am very confused... Maybe it is a godaddy.com issue  `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5edf/1`